# Non-significant variables in the best model

Tags: generalized-least-squares

I am trying to to run model selection on a large dataset (>500 samples and > 50 vars). I ran GLS (using a self written script for selecting models based on AICc), but the problem is that the best GLS model includes many non-significant vars (over-fitted model I suppose). Other possibilities are Forward Selection and Lars, but these do not account for spatial autocorrelation which seems to be strong in my data. I would like to have some advice on other approaches.

Comment: What in statistical theory gave you the idea that insignificant variables are harmful to a model, or that variable selection isn't anything more than a mirage?

Comment: Thank you Frank! The problem is that the best model includes many variables (>10) with high p-values and small coefficients, which make it hard to interpret. I was just wondering maybe there are other ways to get smaller subset of variables.

Comment: (1) hard not to point out that AIC based criteria are intended to produce the result you're not happy and favored over a p-value cut-off that will produce an even worse model (2) you might get a better answer if you expand your question to mention which part of the three classical methods you've considered (a) variable reduction without looking at outcome (PCA, redundant variables etc) (b) shrinkage methods (elastic net) (c) cross-validation methods (deletion substitution addition) and (3) if you somehow show awareness regarding the mirage issue mentioned above.

Comment: Data reduction masked to $Y$ is a good idea.  Seeking to remove "insignificant" variables is not, and having those variables in the model does not make it harder to interpret in many cases.  AIC is mainly just another $P$-value cutoff.